# Are transaction simulations supposed to throw an error if it leaves an account below rent-exempt balance?

Tags: transactions

Simulating a transaction that leaves the balance of a 0-data SystemAccount below rent-exemption on https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector returns success but throws `Transaction leaves an account with data with a lower balance than rent-exempt minimum` when the transaction is actually sent.

Related: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23670

Comment: This is one of those rare questions that sounds like an actual bug, and belongs on GitHub Issues rather than Stack Exchange. If you've determined this to be a bug in transaction simulation, can you post evidence of that here? https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/new/choose

Comment: @steveluscher Looked more into it, and it seems like its just a UI issue on explorer because it only displays `InstructionError`s and not `TransactionError`s. The `simulateTransaction()` RPC call works fine in that it does indeed return the `InvalidRentPayingAccount` `TransactionError` in such cases. However, explorer inspector gives no indication of that and instead only shows the program logs, which return success

Comment: Awesome! Can you file a GitHub issue at that link, against the Explorer itself, and close this Stack Exchange question. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug that belongs on the Solana GitHub Issues tracker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug that belongs on the Solana GitHub Issues tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue opened at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26657 . Can't seem to close my own question without votes from others.